# how to call insert method when click on product?

Tags: nopcommerce

I want to display 10 most viewed product in category page i was made insert method for that in

```
nopCommerce_3.20_Source\Libraries\Nop.Services\Catalog\ProductService.cs
```

---

```
public virtual void InsertMostViewProduct(MostViewProduct product)
{
        if (product == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("product");
        //insert
        _mostviewRepository.Insert(product);

        //clear cache
        _cacheManager.RemoveByPattern(PRODUCTS_PATTERN_KEY);

        //event notification
        _eventPublisher.EntityInserted(product);

}
```

My question is that how should i call this method when i click on product and that entry save in database?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked your first question about displaying 10 most viewed  product.

you have to add this functionality to the product service and in the catalog controller of the `Nop.Web` project you have to add called the newly created method in the product service in the Product Action